# Can I get the line number for a definition from texdef?

Tags: tools, texdef

With `texdef` it is easy to find definitions for (La)TeX commands. It can show what a definition for a given command is and also in what file it is to be found. Sometimes it would be convenient to also learn the line number for the definition it shows. Is this possible with `texdef`?

Take for instance `\section`. `texdef -t latex -F section` returns

```
\section first defined in "/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls".

\section:
\long macro:->\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@ }{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}{\normalfont \Large \bfseries }
```

For ease of getting to the definition of `\section` in article.cls it would be convenient to get the line number to where the definition starts so that I may open the file in an editor and go to that line number instead of having to search the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `texdef` version 1.6 from 2012/05/02 you can use the `--source`/`-s` option which makes the script look in the source file for the original definition including line number. Without this it only uses `\show` inside a (La)TeX call. Note that `-s` is not compatible with all macro definitions, just normal formatted ones. Verbatim macros etc. might not be found.

```
$ latexdef -s section
% article.cls, line 312:
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

If you also use `-F` option the full path is displayed:

```
$ latexdef -F -s section
% /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls, line 312:
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

Here `latexdef` is equivalent to `texdef -t latex`. You can also create a symlink from `latexdef` to `texdef` as stated in the INSTALL file. Unfortunately TeX Live doesn't include the symlinks.

Comment: Should I also add an `--edit` option which opens a text editor at the found line?

Comment: If that is possible it would be fantastic. For cases where `texdef` is run from within Emacs it might also be possible to write an Emacs function for it.

Comment: @N.N.: The problem is to figure out how to call the editor. I know it for Vim `+LINENUMBER FILE`, but other editor it is different. There need to be a config setting for this.

Answer (score 5):

As explained in the answer to [How can texdef be made to return indented definitions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43384/4427) `texdef` doesn't read the files, but uses TeX with the appropriate file and does `\show\foo` when called by

```
texdef -t latex foo
```

(possibly with other command line options). Macro definitions are not always performed with `\def` or `\newcommand`: many of them are implicitly defined and their definition can't be found in a particular line, even if the program was extended to scan the input files.