# How can texdef be made to return indented definitions?

Tags: tools, texdef

With `texdef` it is easy to find definitions for (La)TeX commands. It can show what a definition for a given command is. For instance if I issue `texdef -t latex \LaTeX` I get the following definitions:

```
\LaTeX:
macro:->\protect \LaTeX  


\LaTeX :
\long macro:->L\kern -.36em{\sbox \z@ T\vbox to\ht \z@ {\hbox {\check@mathfonts \fontsize \sf@size \z@ \math@fontsfalse \selectfont A}\vss }}\kern -.15em\TeX
```

A problem is that the latter is very hard to read because it is just one long line. In the source it is easier to read because it is indented. It reads:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeX}{L\kern-.36em%
        {\sbox\z@ T%
         \vbox to\ht\z@{\hbox{\check@mathfonts
                              \fontsize\sf@size\z@
                              \math@fontsfalse\selectfont
                              A}%
                        \vss}%
        }%
        \kern-.15em%
        \TeX}
```

Is it possible to make `texdef` return indented definitions?

Indented definitions are much easier to read. Also, indented definitions are preferable if you want to use them as a base for a redefinition because you do not have to indent them yourself to be able to efficiently work with them.

Comment: I think `texdef` is a simple tool. So the easiest way is to write a new script which uses the functionality of `grep`, `texdef` (maybe `find`).

Comment: `texdef` uses `\meaning` from TeX, not the actual  definition text in some file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since v1.5 (04/2012) there exists the `-s`/`--source` option which will *try* to locate the (first) original definition of the macro and display it as it is written in the source file. However, this will not work with all macros due to the dynamic nature of TeX. Especially verbatim and similar special macros can't be properly parsed by `texdef`. If this features fails the definition is printed the "normal" way, so it is save to use this option in any case.

For the example `\LaTeX` macro this looks as follows:

```
$ latexdef -s LaTeX
% latex.ltx, line 1328:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeX}{L\kern-.36em%
        {\sbox\z@ T%
         \vbox to\ht\z@{\hbox{\check@mathfonts
                              \fontsize\sf@size\z@
                              \math@fontsfalse\selectfont
                              A}%
                        \vss}%
        }%
        \kern-.15em%
        \TeX}
```

If the `-F` option is used in addition the full file path is displayed, which can be useful if you want to have a closer look at the source.

```
$ latexdef -Fs LaTeX
% /home/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx, line 1328:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeX}{L\kern-.36em%
...
```

Comment: I find texdef to be an extremely useful tool for checking `\LaTeX2e` macros from the kernel or packages. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In order to show definitions of commands, `texdef` runs (La)TeX with an appropriate preamble. Then it uses the primitive `\meaning` to show on screen the definition. The output of `\meaning` for a macro is

```
<token>:
<prefixes> macro:<parameter text>-><replacement text>
```

In cases of a "robusted command" `texdef` shows also the internal command, which is why you get two lines from `texdef -t latex LaTeX`:

```
\LaTeX:
macro:->\protect \LaTeX  

\LaTeX :
\long macro:->L\kern -.36em{\sbox \z@ T\vbox to\ht \z@ {\hbox {\check@mathfonts \fontsize \sf@size \z@ \math@fontsfalse \selectfont A}\vss }}\kern -.15em\TeX
```

`texdef` does *not* look into the files, which would be almost meaningless anyway: commands can change their meaning (think to `\maketitle`, that is defined twice by `article.cls` depending on the options) or may be defined in ways very different from `\def\macro` or `\newcommand` macro.

For example, you would *never* find `\def\mathrm`, `\newcommand\mathrm` or `\DeclareRobustCommand\mathrm`, as `\mathrm` is (by default) defined by

```
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathrm}{operators}
```

The same holds for many math commands. Thus "finding the exact place where a command is defined" is in general hopeless.

One might think about filtering the output with a "code beautifier", if such a tool were generally available in Perl distributions (this could indeed be a nice feature for `texdef`).

Comment: Just to clarify: So your answer to the question is that `texdef` is based on `\meaning` which does not return indented code and, thus, `texdef` cannot be made to return indented code?

Comment: Yes, that's the sense. Maybe one can think to filtering the answer through a "code beautifier", but I don't know whether there is such a tool generally available on Perl distributions.

Comment: Could you please add such a clarification to your answer to make it clear for future visitors? Yes, sending it to a prettifier that can prettify for a terminal may be a way to solve it.